Unable to Access xui.one local service URL via Browser in Docker Container
I am trying to install and run xui.one on a Docker container based on Ubuntu 20.04. The installation appears to complete successfully, and the logs show:
Installation completed!
Continue Setup: http://172.18.0.2/v8BmrcW

Here, 172.18.0.2 is the container's IP address. However, when I attempt to access the link in my browser, I get the error:

172.18.0.2 took too long to respond.

I also tried accessing http://localhost/v8BmrcW, but it didn’t work either.
My Configuration:
Dockerfile:
FROM ubuntu:24.04
WORKDIR /app
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

COPY install.sh /app/install.sh
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y sudo wget unzip dos2unix python3 && \
    apt-get clean

RUN dos2unix /app/install.sh
RUN chmod +x /app/install.sh

RUN echo '#!/bin/bash\n\
mkdir -p /opt/xui\n\
chmod 777 /opt/xui\n\
if [ ! -f "/opt/xui/.installed" ]; then\n\
    echo "Y" | ./install.sh\n\
    touch /opt/xui/.installed\n\
else\n\
    echo "XUI already installed, starting service..."\n\
fi\n\
tail -f /dev/null' > /app/wrapper.sh && \
chmod +x /app/wrapper.sh

VOLUME ["/var/lib/mysql", "/opt/xui"]
ENTRYPOINT ["/app/wrapper.sh"]

docker-compose.yml:
version: "3.8"
services:
  xui:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - xui_mysql:/var/lib/mysql
      - xui_home:/opt/xui
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
      - "3306:3306"
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - xui_network

volumes:
  xui_mysql:
  xui_home:

networks:
  xui_network:
    driver: bridge

What I Expected:
I expected the setup page to load in my browser when accessing either:
http://172.18.0.2/v8BmrcW (container IP)
http://localhost/v8BmrcW (mapped to host)
What Actually Happened:
Accessing http://172.18.0.2/v8BmrcW resulted in a timeout:
"172.18.0.2 took too long to respond."

Accessing http://localhost/v8BmrcW failed without a response.

The container-private IP addresses aren't usually useful, and you can't access them unless you're on one very specific Docker setup (using the Docker engine directly on a native-Linux host).  Usually you need a docker run -p published port to access a service in a container.  Can you run this installer in a non-interactive mode?  If you, can you RUN it in the Dockerfile?
